# Measures defined with a format_string to Currency are not displayed with this format in Excel Pivot table

Tags: iccube

If I change the standard "Sales" schema, measure Amount to FORMAT_STRING="Currency", the format of the measure is not a Currency value in Excel.

Instead it is something like:
License - Amount 1112600

The underlying query, generated by Excel is:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Amount],[Measures].[Count]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS 
, NON EMPTY Hierarchize(AddCalculatedMembers(DrilldownMember({{DrilldownMember({{DrilldownLevel({[Product].[Product].[All Products]})}}, {[Product].[Product].[Company].&[1]})}}, {[Product].[Product].[Category].&[2]}))) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS  
FROM [Sales]
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

When I execute this in the MDX panel in icCube, I get also the unformatted value for Amount. But when I add 'Formatted_value' to the CELL PROPERTIES like this

```
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

I get the right answer '$1,112,600.00'.

How can I have Excel display the right formatted_value as defined in icCube? ?